# Writing $f(x)=\left |x-2 \right |+\left |x+2 \right |$ without a modulus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Express $f(x)=\left |x-2  \right |+\left |x+2  \right |$ in the non-modulus form. Hence sketch the graph and determine the range of $f$.

Can someone give me some ideas for solving this question? Thanks.

Comment: consider $x\le -2$,$x\ge 2$ and $-2\lt x \lt2$

Comment: Pick some values - large, medium and small - plug them into the formula and see what happens - say $-10, -5, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 5, 10$ After a few you should understand how it all comes together.

Comment: What happens with $|x-2|$ when $x>2$ and when $x<2$? What happens with $|x+2|$ when $x>-2$ and when $x<-2$?

Comment: http://openstudy.com/updates/4fb76440e4b05565342d0132

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Break up the two absolute values. By definition:

$|x-2| =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x-2  & \mbox{if } x-2 \geq 0 \\
  2-x & \mbox{if } x-2 < 0 \end{array}
\right.$

And:

$|x+2| =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x+2  & \mbox{if } x+2 \geq 0 \\
  -x-2 & \mbox{if } x+2 < 0
 \end{array}
\right.$

If you look at those pieces, you see there's basically three ranges we have to consider:

$f(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  ???  & \mbox{if } x \geq 2 \\
  ???  & \mbox{if } x \lt -2 \\
  ??? & \mbox{if } x \in [-2,2)
 \end{array}
\right.$

Simply fill in the $???$s based on the two components.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this question, I advise to you do a kind of "clothesline signals", in other words, for which values $ |x-2| $ is positive or negative, and for which values $ |x+2| $ is positive or negative, like this way : $$ x-2=0 $$ $$x=2$$, for $x<2$, $ F(x)=x-2 $ show negative values, and for $x>2$, $ F(x)=x-2 $ show positive values, then you do the same thing for $x+2$ and analyze the signal of entire equation.